# Error in using NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsmutablearray, multidimensional-array

I am trying to populate an NSMutableArray here named "data" with NSArrays. When I try to retrieve I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Here is my code for poulating

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* data;
```

.m

```
@synthesize data;
```

in viewDidLoad

```
self.data = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray* ar1 = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"text1", @"text2", @"text3", @"text4", nil] autorelease];
[self.data addObject:ar1];
```

Now in other method I am trying to get the inner NSArray back:

```
NSArray* sItem = [NSArray array]; 
sItem = (NSArray*)[self.data objectAtIndex:0];

if (sItem)
{
    if([sItem isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])/////ERROR LINE
    {
        NSLog(@"Its an Array.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `-viewDidLoad`, you are over-releasing `ar1`. It is returned **already** autoreleased. You know this because you obtained the array via `arrayWithObjects:`, not by `alloc`/`init`.

The pattern is:

```
NSArray * temporaryArray = [ [ [ NSArray alloc ] initWithObjects:obj_0, ..., obj_n, nil ] autorelease ]
```

**or**

```
NSArray * temporaryArray = [ NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj0, ..., obj_n, nil ] ;
```

You should switch your project to ARC--it will handle this for you.

EDIT:

You can also rewrite

```
NSArray* sItem = [NSArray array]; 
sItem = (NSArray*)[self.data objectAtIndex:0];
if (sItem) {
    if([sItem isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]){ /////ERROR LINE
         NSLog(@"Its an Array.");
    }
```

as

```
NSArray* sItem = nil ;
sItem = [self.data objectAtIndex:0];
if( [ sItem isKindOfClass:[ NSArray class ] ] )
{
    NSLog(@"Its an Array.");
}
```

or even

```
NSArray* sItem = [self.data objectAtIndex:0];
if( [ sItem isKindOfClass:[ NSArray class ] ] )
{
    NSLog(@"Its an Array.");
}
```

Notes about your code:

1. You are allocating a new `NSArray` and assigning it to the pointer `sItem`. This array is immediately discarded when you assign another value to `sItem`. Just initialize `sItem` to `nil` instead.
2. You don't need to check `if (sItem)`... Sending `-isKindOfClass:` (or any message in fact) to `nil` will always return `NO`/`nil`/`0`.

Finally, I often check for the presence of an array by doing something like:

```
if ( sItem.length > 0 ) { /* yes, valid, non-empty array */ }
```

This shortcut is especially good for strings.

Comment: no problem. I updated my answer with some extra comments about your code that might help you.

Comment: Thanks. Those tips are helpful to me.